# plane given with a line on it -> build a rectangle in the plane with the line as the diagonal of the rectangle (in 3D)

Tags: geometry

(Everything's in 3D)
Firstly a plane is given. On this plane I'm drawing a line. The beginning and ending point of the line is given therefore. 
What I have to do is to use the line as the diagonal of the rectangle to create the rectangle. For this I just need the other two missing points which are also in the very same plane I've got.

How can I determine the missing two points?

In 2D for example if you have like point B (6|4) and C (1|2) then you can conclude that A is on (1|4) and D is on (6|2).

But I struggle to find a method/algorithm to do so in a 3D world.

PS: If I used the wrong tag please tell me another suggestion, thx!

Comment: Note that infinitely many rectangles can be formed of two given points . In your case , the points you found are two of many . To form a unique rectangle , one needs atleast 3 points .

Comment: The corners of the rectangle are on a circle of which the diagonal is the diameter. The circle is of course on the plane.

Comment: Is there still infinite possible rectangle if I fix both points to a defined plane? I mean shouldn't it then behave exactly as in 2D?

Comment: How is the line defined? Is it as two 3D points that happen to be on the line, or are the two points given on some local coordinates on the plane?

Answer (score 0):

In your 2-D example, you can only reach that conclusion about the other vertices of the rectangle because you’re making the unstated assumption that the sides of the rectangle are parallel to the coordinate axes. If you remove that assumption, then there’s an infinite number of rectangles with that diagonal.

You’re in the same situation in 3-D. There’s no obvious counterpart to “parallel to the axes” for an arbitrary plane, so you’ll need to come up with additional constraints to determine the rectangle uniquely.

Comment: thanks finally I do understand it.

Comment: so if I make the rectangle parallel to an extra plane then I could build it up right? in this case the extra plane should be perpendicular to the plane given in the first place.

Comment: Equivalently, pick some line on the plane to define the directions of the sides of the rectangle.

Comment: I'm sorry but actually I don't get how I can define directions by that.

Comment: Call that line the “$x$-axis” on the plane. The “$y$-axis” is orthogonal to it, so now you’ve got the directions of the rectangle sides.